# How are cells of a table impacted by declaring an event in a col element?

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml, standards

When an event, such as onclick, is declared in a col element for an HTML table does that event impact the cells referenced by the col element?  Is the event ignored?  Does something else happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great question.

[The spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#edef-COL) says:

```
<!ATTLIST COL                          -- column groups and properties --
  %attrs;                              -- %coreattrs, %i18n, %events ---
```

where [`%events` says](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html#events):

```
<!ENTITY % events
 "onclick     %Script;       #IMPLIED  -- a pointer button was clicked --
  ondblclick  %Script;       #IMPLIED  -- a pointer button was double clicked--
  onmousedown %Script;       #IMPLIED  -- a pointer button was pressed down --
  onmouseup   %Script;       #IMPLIED  -- a pointer button was released --
  onmouseover %Script;       #IMPLIED  -- a pointer was moved onto --
  onmousemove %Script;       #IMPLIED  -- a pointer was moved within --
  onmouseout  %Script;       #IMPLIED  -- a pointer was moved away --
  onkeypress  %Script;       #IMPLIED  -- a key was pressed and released --
  onkeydown   %Script;       #IMPLIED  -- a key was pressed down --
  onkeyup     %Script;       #IMPLIED  -- a key was released --"
  >
```

So yes, it appears events are *supposed* to be supported for the `td`s.

However "supposed to" is a far cry from "does". The only way to know is to test in all browsers and hope it works in future browsers too.

On second thought, just use [event delegation](http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2008/07/23/javascript-event-delegation-is-easier-than-you-think/) and bind once to the parent `table` instead. That will work now and forever more.